# Error after including plugins in karma.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, karma-jasmine, webpack-dev-server, karma-webpack

This is my code inside **karma.config.js**:

I'm using Webpack 3+ for my project.

```
module.exports = config => {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: ['./src/components/**/*.spec.ts'],
    plugins: ['karma-jasmine', 'karma-phantomjs-launcher'],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/components/**/*.spec.ts': ['webpack']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    },
    concurrency: Infinity
  });
};
```

After I've included this line of code:

```
 plugins: ['karma-jasmine', 'karma-phantomjs-launcher'],
```

I got the following error:

> Can not load "webpack", it is not registered!

If I don't have this line, everything runs smoothly. The problem is I have to implement PhantomJS. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you provide a repo to reproduce it?

Comment: @juangarcia unfortunately, I can't

Comment: Then as a guess, here is an open case for webpack: https://github.com/vlkosinov/karma-chai-as-promised/issues/5 that could be related, but might be that for some reason the plugin being used by webpack could not be loaded properly and then the registration of webpack failed...

Answer (score 2):

By default, Karma loads all sibling NPM modules which have a name starting with **karma-***.

Looks like you are overriding **plugins** with a new array, which will stop any karma webpack plugins from being loaded.

Therefore, when specifying a new **plugins** array you should add **karma-*** to it:

```
plugins: ['karma-*', 'karma-jasmine', 'karma-phantomjs-launcher'],
```

However, as your plugins are **karma-** prefixed anyway, they should be loaded automatically with the default **plugins** config so you shouldn’t need to specify a plugins array in this case.

I hope this helps.